# Uniqueness of data metric

Tags: statistics, probability, machine-learning

Is there a metric that calculates "uniqueness of data"? For example if i have two sets of 200 observations,

DataSet 1 has 70 unique values but 4 values take up the next 130 observations.
DataSet 2 has 60 unique values but no value is seen more than 4 times.

DataSet 2 would score higher for "uniqueness".

Comment: I think this would be a more appropriate question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I agree with @DaneelOlivaw and it's been posted and answered [there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/343611/7469).

Comment: go ahead. i reposted after his comment.